# Weird effects when one CMD script runs another, from inside a function

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

When one BAT or CMD script runs another (without `call`), that should **not** return, right?
It sometimes does!
And it searches the same function label in that other script?!?

Example: (what do you think the output will be?)

```
@echo off
call :a
call :b
show 5
echo 6
goto :EOF

:a
show 1
echo 2
goto :EOF

:b
if 1==1 show 3
echo 4
goto :EOF
```

with this in `show.cmd` or `show.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo %1
goto :EOF

:a
echo %1 a
goto :EOF
```

The output is (tested in Win10-22H2 and Win7)

```
1 a
3
5
```

I had expected

```
1
```

This means: If another script is run from inside a function, it skips only the rest of the function, then executes the rest. And it tries to find a function with the same name in that other script. The latter can be prevented by prepending `if 1==1`.

Are these effects bugs, or are they features that I can rely on?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known behavior with CMD. From [ss64's page on CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html):

> If you execute a second batch file without using CALL you may run into some buggy behaviour: **if both batch files contain a label with the same name and you have previously used CALL to jump to that label in the first script, you will find execution of the second script starts at the same label.** Even if the second label does not exist this will still raise an error "cannot find the batch label". This bug can be avoided by always using CALL.

You can fix in your script by using `CALL show.cmd 1` instead of `show 1`. More good advice from ss64 on keeping subroutines and functions straight:

> In many cases you will also want to use SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL to keep variables in different batch files completely separate, this will avoid any potential problems if two scripts use the same variable name.